# Transpose a two dimensional Array with one row and many columns into a two dimensional array with many rows and one column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, transpose

I have a two dimensional array with one row and many columns.  I would like to flip this into a two dimensional array variable with one column and many rows.

```
var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(market);
var shrinkLog = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1h3B4HN4mEnBvlx-8aNa9_2ooEZrkY_qLuJcuJXZq7dM").getSheetByName(market);

var dataArr = shrinkLog.getRange(2,3,1,shrinkLog.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

I think the answer is in the map function, but keep returning errors, or getting different versions of the same one dimensional array.  help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I think the answer is in the map function, but keep returning errors, or getting different versions of the same one dimensional array.`. So I'm not sure whether `var dataArr = shrinkLog.getRange(2,3,1,shrinkLog.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].map(c => [c]);` is the solution of your question. Can I ask you about this?

Comment: so, you have `[data1, data2, data3, ...]` and you want `[[data1, data2, data3, ...]]` ?

Comment: @Jaromanda X `shrinkLog.getRange(2,3,1,shrinkLog.getLastColumn()).getValues()` returns `[[data1, data2, data3,,,]]`. So I thought that OP's goal might be `[[data1], [data2], [data3],,,]]`. But unfortunately, I'm not sure about the correct goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your goal as follows.

- From `var dataArr = shrinkLog.getRange(2,3,1,shrinkLog.getLastColumn()).getValues()`, you want to retrieve the result from `[[data1, data2, data3,,,]]` to `[[data1], [data2], [data3],,,]]`.

In your case, `shrinkLog.getRange(2,3,1,shrinkLog.getLastColumn()).getValues()` returns `[[data1, data2, data3,,,]]`. So when your goal is achieved with `map`, the modified script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var dataArr = shrinkLog.getRange(2,3,1,shrinkLog.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].map(c => [c]);
```

#### Note:

- In this case, please enable V8 runtime.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)